# Import/Export between Excel and Calendar list SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-calendar, sharepoint-server

I need to Import/Export between Excel and Calendar list in SharePoint 2019 on Premise.

I have an Excel file that is updated as a calendar file, and I need to be able to have that information update a SharePoint Calendar file,
as well as update the excel file from the SP Calendar file if any changes are made there.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1.Go to site contents -> Add a app -> Import Spreadsheet -> Choose the ‘Range of Cells’ from the worksheet to import data.

2.Create a Calendar View, make the view as default view.

Reference:
https://swethasankaran.com/2015/08/10/importing-an-external-calendarcsv-into-sharepoint/